# Custom Tensorflow loss function that disincentivizes all black pixels

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, objective-functions, image-segmentation

I'm training a Tensorflow model that receives an image and segments the image into foreground and background. That is, if the input image is `w x h x 3`, then the neural network outputs a `w x h x 1` image of `0`'s and `1`'s, where `0` represents background and `1` represents foreground.

I've computed that about 75% of the true mask is background, so the neural network simply trains a model that outputs all `0`'s and gets a 75% accuracy.

To solve this, I'm thinking of implementing a custom loss function that checks if there are more than a certain percentage of `0`'s, and if so, to add a very large number to the loss to disincentivize the all `0`'s strategy.

The issue is that this loss function becomes non-differentiable.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background being an unbalance class is a well known problem in image segmentation. Before digging into custom losses you should take a look to existing ones that address this specific issue like the [Dice Loss](https://pycad.co/the-difference-between-dice-and-dice-loss/) or [Focal Loss](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-focal-loss-for-pixel-level-classification-in-convolutional-neural-networks-720f19f431b1), the latter being more tunable having a extra hyper parameter that can be optimized. You can easily find on github  tensorflow implementations of both.
For a more detailed comparison and reference to other similar losses you can also check this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.14822.pdf).

Comment: Can you briefly summarize Dice Loss and Focal Loss to make your answer more self-contained?